# What is the necessary validation for a contact form?

Tags: php, email

Is it necessary to validate input beyond using [filter_var](http://php.net/filter_var) `FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL` for "to", "bcc" and "cc" address?

Is it enough to use `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` for input like a name and email body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL` is indeed sufficient for cleaning email addresses. It does not correct values, it just strips out invalid characters. This includes newlines and control characters. After that it might not be a valid value, but at least it's safe for use as parameter to the `mail()` function or in From: and Bcc: fields. (Just don't you implement a mailform without captcha!)

`FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` with the default flags is a combination of `strip_tags` and `htmlspecialchars`. It is intended for outputting form values back into a website. It does not make the content safe for *all uses*.
But I think the manual overview explains it best: http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php